# mujs how to make property or method accessible by two names. For example alert and window.alert

Tags: methods, properties, global, mujs

In js properties of global object are accessible as window.method() or method().
For example window.alert('blabla'); and alert('blabla');
How to implement it in mujs?

Now it is:

```
js_newobject(J);
{
    addmethod(J, "alert", window_alert, 1);
}
js_defglobal(J, "window", 0);
js_dostring(J, "function alert(text) { return window.alert(text); }\n");
```

It is not a good solution, because does not work well with properties.
Could you show code snippet, how to make it right?

Answer (score 0):

```
js_pushglobal(J);
{
    addmethod(J, "window.alert", window_alert, 1);
}
js_defglobal(J, "window", 0);
```

seems to work.